# Is JacobiLaplaceSmoother of OpenMesh working correctly for C2 Continuity?

Tags: mesh, openmesh

I have tested the JacobiLaplaceSmoother class for C1 continuity and I think it is working correctly But with C2 continuity, results are weird.

I would like to know if the class is complete for C2 continuity as well.